# How to run `ionic build` in development mode?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using Ionic Framework v5 with Vuejs (created with `ionic start`).

It builds in *production* mode, but I want to build in *development* mode.

I build with `ionic build`, and it outputs:

```
> vue-cli-service build

⠴  Building for production...
```

When I run `vue-cli-service` directly - I get the same output.

When I run `vue-cli-service build --mode development` - it builds in *development* mode.

I tried `ionic build --mode development`, but it still builds in *production* mode.

I tried various additional configuration changes, but couldn't get `ionic build` to build in *development*.

1. How can this be done?
2. When building in *production* mode - the code gets minified. How can I skip the minification?

UPDATE: I get the same results when I try to run it with `ionic build -lcs`:

```
user@ubuntu:~/project (master)$ ionic build -lcs
> vue-cli-service build

⠼  Building for production...Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
⠦  Building for production...
```

Comment: So is the solution to use "npx vue-cli-service build --mode development" ?  It seems to work, but it would be nice if the Ionic team had a way to pass the mode=dev option through from the ionic command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Ionic 6 instead of 5 but running the below command as shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70879835/3813386) should do the trick.

```
ionic build -- --mode development
```

Comment: I have already ditched Ionic a long time ago (I prefer Flutter now), so I can't easily confirm this, but I'll mark this answer as accepted (and reconsider if someone ever complains :) ). thanks!

Comment: thanks! Also works with run: `ionic cap run android -- --mode development`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
ionic build -lcs
```

or if you are trying with cordova then and run un device
try this command
note : datacable must be connect to device all the time

```
ionic cordova build android --device -l
```

run in emulator :

```
ionic cordova emulate android -l
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work :( `ionic build -lcs` still shows "Building for production...".

Comment: Can you please send me exact message

Comment: Yes, I added it as an update to my question.

Comment: what means option  `-l` ? is it `--list` ?

Comment: no -l means live reload

Answer (score 0):

Please use Following code for only in browser

```
ionic serve -w chrome
```

for future reference please follow :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/previewing

Comment: Sorry, I need a way to *build* in development mode, not just serve it with their dev server. I want to deploy the built package on mobile.

Comment: read in reference may u find your solution

Comment: sorry, i looked, neither seems relevant to my question

Comment: Its okay ..will get back when i knew something about this