# Ionic 6 app keeps building in production mode

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to build my app in development mode and am running this script:

`ionic capacitor run ios`

But every time it says building in production mode? Am I missing something? Shouldn't it only build production if I use the --prod flag?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I need to use:

`ionic capacitor run ios -- --mode development`

Answer (score -2):

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html

> `vue-cli-service build` produces a **production-ready** bundle in the dist/ directory, with minification for JS/CSS/HTML and auto vendor chunk splitting for better caching. The chunk manifest is inlined into the HTML.

Answer (score -2):

Check your `angular.json` configuration file and ensure that configurations is set for `dev` environments.

Comment: I'm using vue so I don't have an angular.json file